# Create new scope inside for loop in R

Tags: r, eval

When you create function in loop you got the same issue as in JavaScript you don't copy the value of the variable in for loop but use same reference, so at the end it always last value of the loop. I've thought that I can use same trick as in JavaScript and use IIFE, but this don't work:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- list()
for (e in x) {
   (function(e) {
     y <<- append(y, function() e)
   })(e)
}
y[[1]]()
# => 10
```

I've try to solve it using eval:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- list()
for (e in x) {
   eval(substitute({
     y <<- append(y, function() { e })
   }, list2env(list(e = e))))
}
y[[1]]()
# => 1
y[[9]]()
# => 9
```

but why this code don't work:

```
scope <- function(expr, ...) {
  eval(substitute(expr, list2env(list(...))))
}
x <- 1:10
y <- list()
for (e in x) {
   scope({
     y <<- append(y, function() { e })
   }, e = e)
}
```

got error:

> Error in list2env(list(...)) :    names(x) must be a character vector
>   of the same length as x

Do you know how to create function `scope` or maybe other shorter/better way to create functions in loop in R?

I don't need this for any particular reason, just want to know how R works and how this should be done in R.

Comment: I think the `local/capture` answer on the other question should do what you need.

Comment: Or you could add `force(e)` to your immediate function: `(function(e) {force(e); y <<- append(y, function() e)})(e)` But I would also suggestion avoiding `append()`ing repeatedly in a loop if possible. If you have a lot of values, this is the part that makes R loops "slow". Otherwise they are very fast.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the answer, append was just quickest example that show the issue, this is mainly for shiny observeEvent or downloadHandler.